# Download SSL Corproate Proxy Cert via Linux CLI

Tags: linux, ssl, proxy

How do I download a proxy's SSL cert and save it to a file using the Linux command line.

It's possible to download an ssl cert via the openssl tool: https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file. But this does not work when behind a corporate proxy that re-writes the SSL cert.  I would like to download the proxy's ssl cert.  Changing the HOST and PORT to my proxy's host and port does not work either.

Downloading the cert using my browser works but I need to do this in a bash script.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only extract certificates from the connection which actually get send inside the connection. Within a MITM proxy the root CA you want to have usually does not get send since it is expected to be installed locally as trusted, similar to a public root CA.  And the reason you can extract this MITM CA within your browser is because the browser already has this CA as trusted in the CA store and can thus export it.

Comment: Thanks, this explains why it says: 'no peer certificate available' when i use the openssl s_client on the proxy server.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/139728/how-to-download-the-ssl-certificate-from-a-website#comment1225171_192731), `openssl` 1.1.0 and above support the `-proxy` argument so you can get the proxy's certificates with a command like (`jcenter.bintray.com` is just an example host to connect to)

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -proxy $https_proxy -connect jcenter.bintray.com:443
```

Also see [this script](https://github.com/oss-review-toolkit/ort/blob/main/scripts/import_certificates.sh) for a more complete example how to import the certificate(s) to a JVM keystore and the system certificates.

Comment: `https_proxy` contains the protocol name, i.e.`https://` which openssl does not accept.  The proper command is `openssl s_client -showcerts -proxy ${https_proxy/*:\/\//} -connect jcenter.bintray.com:443`.